# Bootstrap 3 - Make textarea fill table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on creating a forum/bulletin board software. I am having problems when adding the reply section to the thread page, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDDyj/) is what I have so far.

Html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="forum-post-heading-container">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YURsw6g.png" class="img-thumbnail avatar-image forum-image">
                <div class="forum-post-header-padding"></div>
                <div class="forum-post-header-author-name"><a href="./?a=profile&u=test">username</a></div>
            </td>
            <td class="forum-post-contents">
                <textarea id="reply-text" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.forum-post-heading-container{
    padding: 15px;  
}
.forum-image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
}
.forum-post-header-padding{
    height: 5px;    
}
.forum-post-header-author-name{
    text-align: center; 
}
.forum-post-contents{
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 15px;  
}

#reply-text{
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.panel-body` ([panels with tables](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables)), add `.table` class to your table to get 100% width and use `col-*-*` to set your second `td` width:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="forum-post-heading-container">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YURsw6g.png" class="img-thumbnail avatar-image forum-image">
                <div class="forum-post-header-padding"></div>
                <div class="forum-post-header-author-name"><a href="./?a=profile&u=test">username</a></div>
            </td>
            <td class="forum-post-contents col-xs-11">
                <textarea id="reply-text" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Finally, remove the `width` in `#reply-text` and add `text-align: center` in `.forum-post-heading-container`.

Comment: [Dosen't quite work](http://i.imgur.com/UzG0agg.png), I do not like the line on the top, or the squishedness of `forum-post-heading-container`.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I removed the `.panel-body`. If `forum-post-heading-container` is too narrow, then change the `col-xs-11` to `col-xs-10.`